# Does having a registry full of old stuff slow down Windows?

Tags: windows, registry

I know this isn't strictly speaking a programming question but something I always hear from pseudo-techies is that having a lot of entries in your registry slows down your Windows-based PC. I think this notion comes from people who are trying to troubleshoot their PC and why it's running so slow and they open up the registry at some point and see leftover entries from programs they uninstalled ages ago.

But is there any truth to this idea? I would not think so since the registry is essentially just a database and drilling down to an entry wouldn't take significantly longer on a larger registry. But does it?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I'm not looking for advice on how to make a PC run faster, or asking why my PC in particular is slow (it's not), I'm just curious if people who say "bigger registry means slower PC" are accurate or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, not really.

In the old days when machines were slower the answer was yes; but having a modern processor rip through even a 60MB registry is not a problem.

Typically, the real reason a modern machine starts running slow is due to everything from malware to virus scanners: Mcafee, Norton's, etc are prime targets in my mind.

Also, the WinSXS folder tends to grow as service packs and applications are installed.  This seems to have a negative impact on system performance.  There are only two possible solutions in this scenario.  First, if possible, reinstall the OS with the latest service pack already slipstreamed into the install.  Second, if that isn't possible AND you are running Vista with SP1, you can run the vsp1cln.exe tool (see [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766219.aspx)) which will clean up a lot of the older versions of components.  Note that this tool can only be executed once and it does not allow you to roll back.

Comment: The WinSXS makes an impact on disk size, but not really on performance. If you're not using the SXS stuff on disk, it'll just stay there out of the way, and not slowing you down.

Comment: @NotMe Based on your last paragraph, *nix systems should not slowdown over time correct? Because they don't have the WinSXSfolder

Comment: @Abdul: Saying that *nix systems should not slow down just because they don't have a particular feature isn't logical.  There are many reasons a *nix system *could* slow down, but I'm not well versed enough in those to iterate them.

Comment: @NotMe True, there could be something on *nix systems, that isn't on Windows systems, that could be the primary slowdown cause.

Answer (score 7):

I think its a symptom, not a cause, as fever is a symptom of an infection.

When you install windows updates, at least in xp and up, a folder called SXS is maintained for rolling them back. These rollback points are also stored in reg keys.

The size of the sxs(side by side) folder grows exponentially and definitely has been linked to why, when some people simple reinstall with sp3 instead of installing sp1 and rolling up to sp3 they get better performance, even with the same programs installed.

Comment: Would it be harmful to delete this sxs directory?

Comment: I've been told by others that its harmful, and haven't tried it personally. This seems to be the reason that many more advanced devs are VMing their development machines so that its a clean single purpose install with almost no updates. While maintaining their other apps on a dirtier/slower install

Comment: I'm personally getting used to running my dev machine vm on one monitor and the host OS on the other monitor and being able to have it feel as if its really 1 install on 2 monitors, working nicely for me.

Answer (score 5):

1) Start -> Run -> msconfig
2) Check the Startup tab
3) If you don't know what it is, uncheck
4) Reboot

Its not the registry, its the crap you have running in the background.

Answer (score -8):

any problems occur on the registry could also make your computer much slower.the fix registry problems you need to install a [registry cleaner](http://www.windows7-slow.com/computer-running-extremely-slow/) as this will fix the errors and make your pc back to its  normal state.

Comment: Many downloadable registry cleaners are malware in disguise. This is bad advice.